# Connect to Vagrant (VirtualBox VM) over local network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, vagrant

Hi I'm running a local webserver using vagrant virtual machine.

I Normally set the following config line to private network which lets me connect from my host pc using the ip specified

```
config.vm.network :public_network, ip: "192.168.13.37"
```

When its set as public network I get asked:

`What interface should the network bridge to?`

I've ran `ipconfig` and have approximately 30 connections listed, I guessed that i'd want to bridge to my wireless router but everything i type it keeps asking me the same question and disregards my answer.

My guess is that I want to connect using:

**Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:**

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dlink.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : de81::3045:3e4f:203f:401c%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.7
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

But When i put the name in, or the ipv6 address nothing happens.

## Am I going along the right lines, what do i need to do to connect from other devices on the wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to input the index number (instead of the name or ip address) that is printed before this interface in the prompt list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `:bridge` parameter with interface you want it to be attached to:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.13.37", :bridge => <iface>
```

where `<iface>` is interface name you want to bridge to i.e. `eth1` or `wlxc83a35c5342b`, depending of host os used:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.13.37", :bridge => "eth3"
```

Optionally you may also add `auto_config: false` if that would be needed.